# installed fedora in eclipse emulator show blank screen like this

Tags: android, android-emulator, fedora

i have gone through other posts in stack overflow but doesn't help.
i installed  the adt plugin,i have android sdk installed but what is
missing? i tried seeing the logcat but since the emulator doesn't start 
there is not information in logcat.

when ever i start it shows the emulator but if i minimize the emlator and maximize it shows blank screen

before minimizing 
[image: before minimizing]

[image: after minimizing and opening]

some problem with memory i mean memory is insufficient??